# Does Workbook.RefreshAll refresh PivotTables or PivotCaches?

Tags: excel, refresh, pivot-table, vba

If a workbook has 100 Pivot tables all using one single cache, will Workbook.RefreshAll launch 100 refreshes or only 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to answer questions like this is to whip up some code, and test it.

```
Sub RefreshTest()
Dim TimeTaken As Date

TimeTaken = Now()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
TimeTaken = Now() - TimeTaken
Debug.Print Now() & vbTab & "Refresh All" & vbTab & Format(TimeTaken, "HH:MM:SS") & " seconds."

TimeTaken = Now()
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Refresh
TimeTaken = Now() - TimeTaken
Debug.Print Now() & vbTab & "Refresh Specific Cache" & vbTab & Format(TimeTaken, "HH:MM:SS") & " seconds."
End Sub
```

On my PC when testing on a PivotTable with 1048575 rows there's no difference between using RefreshAll and refreshing the PivotCache of one of the PivotTables.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I recently found a post on on [mrexcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/571489-vba-refresh-all-pivot-tables.html#post2826406) asking about the differences on either cycling through each pivot table and updating each one individually or using `.RefreshAll`.

[Jerry Sullivan](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/571489-vba-refresh-all-pivot-tables.html#post2829263) posted an answer (Aug 16, 2011) with the following comment (version #2 --> `.RefreshAll`, version #1 --> cycling through pt's):

> The version #2 is probably more efficient. In addition to not stepping through each sheet, it probably updates each PivotCache once, whereas if any PivotTables share the same PivotCaches, those PivotCaches will get refreshed more than once with version #1.

Although, I do note that he said "probably".

Comment: Jerry's comment applies to the situation where you refresh every PivotTable separately instead of refreshing the PivotCache that they share. That's not the case here.